# Coloring custom data types

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Working with a custom framework and I was curious to know how I would be able to enable the VS custom coloring on data types and other similar things.

Like the normal Blue coloring on the data type for example, when you type `int roar` the word "int" is colored blue. In the framework that I am using, the data types is not colored blue, as an example `pok_int roar`

So I was wondering if there was a way for me to enable the coloring system in visual studio for custom Data Types.

Comment: You can adjust the coloring by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Comment: Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265717(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @boca, hey how would i be able to add keywords in their ?

Comment: Not really. I know Resharper added some items in there but I'm not sure how that works

Comment: @Slaks: of course you are right.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`int` is colored blue because it's a keyword, not because it's a special type.

Comment: No way, for me to customize coloring on specific keywords ? or get a extension or add on like resharper which would color these specified specific keywords ?

Comment: Not without an extension.  I don't know what extensions do that

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Environments holds all modifications you are allowed to make.  If it is not in this list, it can't be done with the default install.  For HTML though, you can make those types of changes for specific tags, for example, by changing the formatting for the tag.

Tools -> Options -> Environments -> Keywords -> Keyword -> Item foreground

Tools -> Options -> Environments -> Keywords -> Identifier -> Item foreground

You cannot however do exactly what you are wanting to do but, at the very least, you now know how to make some modifications.